# stopping buttons in hbox to expand vertically

Tags: gtk, gtk3

In gtk+3.0 in windows 7.

I am creating a button and packed them into horizontal box. I have set the expand to FALSE. Now the button is not expanding in x direction but expanding vertically. I don't want the button to expand vertically also.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = NULL;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Layout using BOX");
    //gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 50, 300);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkWidget* button[5] = {NULL};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::stringstream buton_label;
        buton_label << "Button ";
        buton_label << (i + 1);
        button[i] = gtk_button_new_with_label(buton_label.str().c_str());
        gtk_widget_set_hexpand(button[i], FALSE);

        g_signal_connect(button[i], "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked_cb), (gpointer)window);
    }

    GtkWidget *hbox = NULL;
    hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    //hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button[i], FALSE, TRUE, 10);
    }

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), hbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In GTK 3, the widget tells the container how it wants to be expanded (was the opposite in GTK 2). So you need to use the `hexpand` and `vexpand` properties of your widget for horizontal and vertical expanding, with functions like [`gtk_widget_set_hexpand`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-hexpand). Same for alignment with `halign` and `valign`.

**EDIT**:

As an exception to the rule, read the documentation of [gtk_box_pack_start](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-start) and its `fill` parameter:

> *fill*
>
> TRUE if space given to child by the expand option is actually
>   allocated to child , rather than just padding it. This parameter has
>   no effect if expand is set to FALSE. **A child is always allocated the
>   full height of a horizontal GtkBox and the full width of a vertical
>   GtkBox**. This option affects the other dimension.

So if you want to control the other dimension, put the horizontal box inside a vertical box where you'll set `expand` to `FALSE` when calling `gtk_box_pack_start`.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = NULL;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Layout using BOX");
    //gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 50, 300);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkWidget* button[5] = {NULL};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::stringstream buton_label;
        buton_label << "Button ";
        buton_label << (i + 1);
        button[i] = gtk_button_new_with_label(buton_label.str().c_str());
        gtk_widget_set_hexpand(button[i], FALSE);

//        g_signal_connect(button[i], "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked_cb), (gpointer)window);
    }

    GtkWidget *hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button[i], FALSE, FALSE, 10);
    }

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), hbox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Intead of using boxes (which may be a bit difficult to use because you have to figure out how things expand), try using the more powerful `GtkGrid`. It works with the hexpand/vexpand properties of the chidren like I said above.

Comment: Buttons are vertically expanding, even adding gtk_widget_set_hexpand(button[i], FALSE);

Comment: `hexpand` is **horizontal** expand. For vertical expand, use `vexpand`.

Comment: Same result, still the buttons are expanding vertically

Comment: the same here, set_vexpand(false) doesnt't work for vertical non-expanding.

Comment: Yes, it seems GtkBox seems to be a special case, I changed my answer accordingly. What I said remains for other containers like GtkGrid.

Comment: @liberforce I just ran into the same issue in Gtkmm with boxes. I had grids nested inside boxes and the valign issue persisted. Converting everything to grids and using your strategy did the trick. I have full control over the vertical alignment now. This is extremely frustrating behavior...

Comment: Same problem as everybody else with a FlowBox container. I don't think GtkBox is a special case where this doesn't work, so much as GtkGrid is a special case where it *does*, and it's broken everywhere else.